# Is it possible to resize the "consolidated comments" sections in SP workflow task?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I was wondering if it is possible to resize the consolidated comments section? I was informed it was, but can't find enough info to assist in doing so. I'm new to modifying items on Sharepoint, your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHr2Q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error, I figured out how to resize the area without having to go into the code... it was as simple as going back into infopath and resizing there and re-publishing.